# Get data from filepond svelte submit to client

Tags: filepond

i'm trying to send data from a svelte server action to the client.
I'm using Filepond, and sending the data to the server with the server="?/submit"

i have this code on the server:

+page.server.svelte

```js
// ...
export const actions = {
    submit: async ({ request }) => {
          // do something
          return { text: "Hey!"};
    },
};
```

How can i get the text, "Hey!", on the client? if it maters, i'm using svelte-filepond to send the request:

+page.svelte

```html
<FilePond
        bind:this={pond}
        {name}
        server="?/submit"
        allowMultiple={true}
        onprocessfiles={done} <!-- runs done function when all files gets uploaded -->
/>
```

and

```js
  export let form;
  $: console.log(form?.text)
```

outputs undefined.